# typeahead not returning values

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap typeahead

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" ng-change="invalid_tickr=false" typeahead="tickr for tickr in tickrValues($viewValue)" class="form-control" required autofocus>
```

controller.js

```
    $scope.tickrValues = function(val) {   
      var url = // some url
      $ajax.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        return data.map(function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            console.log(item.value);
            return item.value;
        });
    });
   }
```

This function is printing item.value correctly to the console but it's not returning the values.

Comment: Its typo change `$ajx` to `$ajax`

Answer (score 2):

You missed to get the array using .get(). If you have collection of some arrays in the map suppose if you want to get all the array values in collection use .get() method

```
$scope.tickrValues = function(val) {   
      var url = // some url
      $ajax.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        var res = $.map(data, function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            console.log(item.value);
            return item.value;
        }).get();
        return res;
    });
   }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that. I am getting an error data.map...get() not a function.

Comment: I am still getting an error - $.map(...).get is not a function

Answer (score 1):

In Angular I would suggest to have your ajax calls in factories rather than controller so that you need not rerun the angular digest as well as to make your code look neater and maintainable.

Hence your angular factory with your ajax call will look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.factory',[])
       .factory('restCall',['$http',function($http) {
           return {
                factoryCall: function(url) {
                   return $http.get(url);
                }
           }
}]); 

angular.module('myApp',[])
       .controller('myApp.controller',['restCall','$scope', function(restCall,$scope) {
         $scope.tickrValues = function(val) { 
           restCall.factoryCall(url).then(function(data) {
               return data.map(function(item) {
                  console.log(item);
                  console.log(item.value);
                  return item.value;
              });
           });
         }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think that the problem is with digest loop.

Answer (score 0):

you should put return statement before **$ajax.get**

Here is the update code.

```
var url = // some url
     return  $ajax.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        return data.map(function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            console.log(item.value);
            return item.value;
        });
    });
   }
```

Hope this work.

Comment: After adding that also it didn't work but on changing success to then it worked.

Comment: ok great.I missed it.you used angular syntax  for success with jquery $ajax